# Outlook 2013 causes Microsoft account authentication failure

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-account

When Outlook is running, it will periodically "talk" to Microsoft to validate my account, and always fails validation.  By that I mean I can go into my [Account activity](https://account.live.com/Activity) see that each time Outlook makes a call to "roaming.officeapps.live.com" (seen with Fiddler), and directly correlates with the number of "Incorrect password entered" (with the "Browser/app" listed as "Internet Explorer") events.  Eventually this locks my account.

My Microsoft account password is up-to-date in Windows 8.1 (Your Account Settings), Office (2013 Pro), and everywhere else.  Even in Outlook's Office Account section, I made sure the password is current.  Again, this only happens when Outlook is open, and will repeat about once per minute.  This happens even when I run Outlook in Safe Mode.

I'm assuming I'm missing a place where I have to update my credentials, but I don't know where they would be.  I think I've looked everywhere.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with you. Have you solved this out, yet?

Comment: Yes.  I found the issue buried deep in one of the Microsoft forums (I'll check later and post the exact threads if I can find them).  It's a legitimate bug that Microsoft doesn't seem to care about.  The issue is that I had an Exchange mailbox with the same email as my Microsoft account.  Windows tries to authenticate the Microsoft Account with the credentials for Exchange, which fails.  The only workaround at the moment is to make the passwords the same (lame, I know, but it works).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to make the password same.

Comment: I have the exact same issue! Can you post a link to the bug you found, I want to see if we can up-vote it.